# Identifying an electronic component

Tags: identification, components

I'm trying to repair an old stereo and I'm fairly sure I blew one of the components. I've never seen one of these before, and after research here and there I can't identify what it is - it's this cap looking silver thing in the center of the pictures:

[image]

[image]

So it's not a cap, it has 75000 written on the side of it and Y101 on the board, if that's any help.

Comment: Guessing: oscillator crystal. Can't read the markings. Does the "stereo" feature a clock?

Comment: As I suspected, it took a split second to any trained paid of eyes. Thanks a lot to all of you :-)

Comment: @greybeard yes it does :-)

Comment: A crystal is unlikely to show visible evidence of failure. Why do you believe that it has failed?

Comment: @Mattman944 because I applied too much voltage on the wrong pin (8v), the board drawn about 3 amps for a few seconds then smoke escaped from it, or at least I assumed it was from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is most probably a 75kHz crystal, check if it is connected to pins 78 and 79 of Valence AP702 controller.

[image]

Comment: You are very correct sir, after having a look at the datasheet's schematics, this is precisely what is connects to. And I've also learned now how to figure this out by myself next time, many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It is a tuning fork style crystal resonator in a cylindrical can. The designator Y101 indicates that as well.

Something like [this](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/filter/crystals/171?s=N4IgjCBcpgbFoDGUBmBDANgZwKYBoQB7KAbRAGZzZYBWAJhAF0CAHAFyhAGU2AnASwB2AcxABfAnTA0ADAhDJI6bPiKkQAdhoACANYAJAF5NWHSCACqg-mwDyKALI40WAK68c4ggFoG0BVB8rqrEkGQ0TGISIH5kiLwAnlhsmJFAA).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a crystal to me.

From wikipedia:
[image]
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_oscillator#/media/File:Crystal_Packages.jpg